# How to render a table from a view in the footer section of _Layout view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing a solution to enter project-split times in the fullcalendar jquery application. A SQL view shows incomplete days (where entered time is not equal to 8 hours) and renders the table from the entity model in the Generate view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<support_tickets.Models.DailyHours>
    
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Generate</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Start)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Week)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hours)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
    
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Week)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours)
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
                }
    
            </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'd like to render the same table in the footer section of the _Layout view, to see everything on one page. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me - creating a partial view from the PartialViewResult action.

In Controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult IncompleteDays()
{
    ticketsEntities entities = new ticketsEntities();
    var ent = entities.DailyHours.ToList();
    return PartialView(ent);
}
```

Create a partial View from the action, with the table:

```
@model IEnumerable<support_tickets.Models.DailyHours>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">

        <table class="table table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Start)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Week)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hours)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       
                        @Convert.ToDateTime(item.Start).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Week)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then call the action from the footer section of the _Layout view:

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("IncompleteDays", "Home");}
```